# Go networking best practices for UDP server

Tags: go, dns

I'm writing a DNS server in Go to learn how DNS works and how to write a real, potentially useful program in Go.

One of the reasons I chose Go was for its Go routines instead of threads.

Currently, my DNS server doesn't really do much, it sends the same response for every query it receives.

One thing that confuses me is that my DNS server, even with its Go routines and even though it's small and doesn't do much is 10x slower than BIND.

I ran a program called `dnsblast` to send lots of DNS queries at once and these are my results:

```
BIND
Sending 10,000 queries = 39,000 pps

My server
Sending 10,000 queries = 3,000 pps
```

Also, as I increase the number of packets I send per second, the server responds to less and less of the queries.

For example:
When sending 1,000 queries, the server responds to 100%, but when sending 10,000 queries the server responds to just 66%.

Is there anything to do with networking in Go that could be limiting the performance of my DNS server? Are there settings in Go I can configure?

Currently, the main program looks like this:

```
func main() {

    serv, err := net.ListenPacket("udp", ":53")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer serv.Close()

    for {
        tmp := make([]byte, 512)
        num_bytes, addr, _ := serv.ReadFrom(tmp)
        go handleQuery(serv, bytes.NewBuffer(tmp[:num_bytes]), addr)
    }

}
```

This seems to be a pretty standard way of creating a server in Go from what I've read online.

1. Listen for packets
2. Save packet data in a buffer
3. Process each packet using a separate Go routine.

Are there any best practices to improve my server's throughput or does the server look okay and it's just my partial DNS implementation is slow?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have performance issues, then you start by profiling. If I were to guess, the next step would be to have a pool of reusable buffers, rather than allocating new ones for every packet. Then maybe a fixed pool of handlers so you can buffer requests that you can't handle immediately. (also, don't ignore errors)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Go's UDP support is suboptimal. The implementation allocates memory. What helps a bit is to run the loop in parallel. Increased buffer sizes on OS level limit package loss.